# Open html page in a BootstrapDialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-dialog

In my Spring projet, I have a navigation bar where I have the follow links:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LigaDesportiva</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="clube.html">Clubes</a></li>
            <li><a href="dirigente.html">Dirigentes</a></li>
            <li><a href="jogadore.html">Jogadores</a></li>
            <li><a href="liga.html">Ligas</a></li>
            <li><a href="usuario.html">Usu&aacute;rios</a></li>
          </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">${usuario.nome} <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="usuario_perfil.html">Perfil</a></li>
                        <li><a href="usuario_historico.html">Hist&oacute;rico</a></li>
                        <li><a href="logout.html">Sair</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>
```

I need each link open in a BootstrapDialog like the below, available in the site http://www.jqueryrain.com/?iFhFXJv3:

```
BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: 'Draggable Dialog',
            message: 'Try to drag on dialog title to move your dialog.',
            draggable: true
        });
```

For this, I need three things:

1) load the content of the file in a javascript variable
2) capture the title of the page from tag  and use as title of the window
3) capture the 'body' section from the page and use as message for the window

I try this:

```
$("a").click(function(){
   var url = $(this).attr("href");
   var destino = load(url);
   var title_page = $(destino).filter("title").text();
   var message_page = $(destino).filter("body").text();
   BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: $(title_page),
            message: $(message_page),
            draggable: true
        });
});
```

But don't work. What I made wrong? The console of the browser don't show any error, but the page isn't opening in the dialog.

**UPDATE**

I change the code used to this, but still don't work.

```
function load_page(url) {
    var responseText = '<div></div>';
    $(responseText).load(url);
    var title_text = $(responseText).attr("title").text();
    var message_text = $(responseText).attr("body").text();
    BootstrapDialog.show({
        title: $(title_text),
        message: $(message_text),
        draggable: true
    });
}
```

But in the console of the browser (Firefox) this error is displayed when I click on the link:

```
TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined
```

Someone knows how I can finally be able to capture and handle de content of target page?

Comment: What is the load(url); method?

Comment: probably one of the things it's wrong with code. I have used previouly this function this way: $("content").load(url). what I want here is read the content of the html file and save in the variable.

Comment: how can you load the entire html page without the code just by calling the `name & body` of the page ?

Comment: `var element = '<div something="something else"></div>';
$(element).attr('something'); // returns 'something else'`

Answer (score 0):

You could try using iframe or something similar inside your bootstrap modal .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use callback because of async load. Something like this:

```
$("#data").load(url, function(responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
console.log(responseText);

var title_page = responseText.filter("title").text();
var message_page = responseText.filter("body").text();
BootstrapDialog.show({
        title: $(title_page),
        message: $(message_page),
        draggable: true
    });


})
```

Comment: what kind of element is being represented by 'data'? where I should put it in the page?

Comment: Any element with attribute id='data'